# Why has logstash.yml to be writable?

Tags: docker, configuration, logstash, elk

This sounds quite intuitive to me that a conf file should not be changed by the application using it. Thus, a read-only file should be suited here.

But launching a containerized version of logstash whose settings are set using *docker config* system mame me think some may disagree :

```
configs:
  - source: ELK_LOGSTASH_SETTINGS
    target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
  - source: ELK_LOGSTASH_CONF
    target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
```

> elk_logstash.1.mlu30v8380d7@vmwhatever    | 2021/09/17 09:01:59
> error: open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml: read-only file
> system

[Docker-compose config doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#configs) states that " *Configs cannot be writable because they are mounted in a temporary filesystem*".
Thus, there seems to be not workaround using "config" mechanism here.

I will eventually use a volume instead, but I am still puzzled and would like to understand **why does logstash settings has to be writable?**
Is this a kind of pattern ?

Answer (score -1):

It might look like file need to change some permission of file for docker process to read it

Comment: It was not my point : I want to know about why it has to be writable, not how to make it writable

Comment: well the the process within docker container has a , container local user:group so the process might need same permission on file for reading as well (it's not trying to write but read) it will try to modify it for it's access. that lead request for modify the file ownership something like chown 1000:1000 , and docker config are immutable so they can't be modified